# Shift a fop table to the right

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm implementing `FOP` by mixing `xsl` and `xml` files to obtain as a result a `PDF` file.

But I can't seem to shift the table to the right correctly.
I manipulated the following FOP `attributes` related to the `table`:

1. `start-indent`: But the contents of the table shift more than the
   shifting value of the `start-indent` by two times corrupting the overall layout
2. `margin-left`: This attribute seems to effect the same way on the table as `start-indent`

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you specify, say, `start-indent="20mm"` on the `fo:table` element and `start-indent="0mm"` on `fo:table-body` (and also on `fo:table-header` and `fo:table-footer`, if they are used). For example:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="60mm" 
          border-style="solid" start-indent="20mm">
  <fo:table-column column-width="40%"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="60%"/>
  <fo:table-body start-indent="0mm" >
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell border-style="solid">
        <fo:block>Col1</fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell border-style="solid">
        <fo:block>Col2</fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

[`start-indent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#start-indent) is an inherited property. Resetting it makes it not apply to the child areas of `fo:table`.

I was unable to make it work with [`margin-left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#margin-left) (a non-inherited property). This might be a FOP bug (it works with [XEP](http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html)).

See also the [Interpreting Indent Inheritance in XSL-FO](http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/IndentInheritance) article on the Xmlgraphics-fop wiki
(especially the "Further examples with tables" section).

Answer (score 1):

If the solution above doesn't work, there is another way. It's just a table with an empty first column. So it looks like a right-shifted table.

```
<fo:block wrap-option="no-wrap">
    <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" width="100%">
        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(60)" />
        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(20)" />
        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(20)" />
        <fo:table-header />
        <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell />
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>John</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>Doe</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell />
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>Peter</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>Parker</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</fo:block>
```

- The table has a width of 100% and the first column is empty.
- The columns have percentaged width.
- The % in column-width is apparently not allowed, use proportional-column-width instead.
- In this example there are no header names, but you can add names except of the first column.
- If a border is needed, it should be done except of the first one logically.